# Memory Leak in plugin action

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, memory

I made a plugin that basically reads a CSV file and imports data to relevant tables.

However, the action seems to create an error:

> Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65015808 bytes) in **/var/www/proj/wp-includes/functions.php** on line

which led me to this code in functions.php:

```
function wp_ob_end_flush_all() {
    $levels = ob_get_level();
    for ($i=0; $i<$levels; $i++)
        ob_end_flush();
}
```

I did a Google and came across two popular solutions, both of which didn't seem to work.

> Solution 1: disabling zlib - this is already disabled.
>   Solution 2: `remove_action('shutdown', 'wp_ob_end_flush_all', 1);`

Solution 2 still errors  but with no message, which, isn't exactly ideal.

This is the script that's causing the error:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    # load core wp fnc
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-load.php';
    # load db functions
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
    # load admin fnc
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-content/plugins/vendor-module/admin/inc/admin-functions.php';

    global $wpdb;

    $admin_functions = new vendor_module_admin_functions();

    # get csv
    $file = $_FILES['csv'];

    $name = $file['name'];
    $dir = $file['tmp_name'];

    # rm spaces, replace with _
    $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);

    $file_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-content/plugins/vendor-module/uploads/import/'. $name;

    # if successfully moved, carry on, else return
    $moved = ($file['error'] == 0 ? true : false);

    $error = false;

    if (!$moved) {
        echo 'Error! CSV file may be incorrectly formatted or there was an issue in reading the file. Please try again.';
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($dir, $file_location);

        $id = $_POST['val'];
        $type = $_POST['type'];

        $table = ($type == 1 ? 'vendor_module_type_one' : 'vendor_module_type_two');

        $handle = fopen($file_location, 'r');

        $parts = array();
        $components = array();

        $i = 0;

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false)
        {
            if (is_array($data)) {
                if (empty($data[0])) {
                    echo 'Error! Reference can\'t be empty. Please ensure all rows are using a ref no.';
                    $error = true;

                    continue;
                }

                # get data
                $get_for_sql = 'SELECT `id` FROM `'. $wpdb->prefix. $table .'` WHERE `ref` = %s';
                $get_for_res = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($get_for_sql, array($data[0])));

                if (count($get_for_res) <= 0) {
                    echo 'Error! Reference has no match. Please ensure the CSV is using the correct ref no.';
                    $error = true;

                    exit();
                }

                $get_for_id = $get_for_res[0]->id;

                # create data arrays
                $parts[$i]['name'] = $data[1];
                $parts[$i]['ref'] = $data[2];
                $parts[$i]['for'] = $get_for_id;

                $components[$i]['part_ref'] = $data[2];
                $components[$i]['component_ref'] = $data[3];
                $components[$i]['sku'] = $data[4];
                $components[$i]['desc'] = utf8_decode($data[5]);
                $components[$i]['req'] = $data[6];
                $components[$i]['price'] = $data[7];

                unset($get_for_id);
                unset($get_for_res);
                unset($get_for_sql);

                $i++;
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
        unlink($file_location);

        # get unique parts only
        $parts = array_unique($parts, SORT_REGULAR);

        # check to see if part already exists, if so delete
        $search_field = ($type == 1 ? 'id_field_one' : 'id_field_two');

        $check_sql = 'SELECT `id` FROM `'. $wpdb->prefix .'vendor_module_parts` WHERE `'. $search_field .'` = %d';
        $delete_parts_sql = 'DELETE FROM `'. $wpdb->prefix .'vendor_module_parts` WHERE `'. $search_field .'` = %d';
        $delete_components_sql = 'DELETE FROM `'. $wpdb->prefix .'vendor_module_components` WHERE `part_id` = %d';

        $check_res = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($check_sql, array($id)));

        if ($check_res) {
            $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($delete_parts_sql, array($id)));
        }

        $part_ids = $admin_functions->insert_parts($parts, $type);

        unset($parts);
        unset($delete_parts_sql);
        unset($search_field);
        unset($check_sql);
        unset($check_res);
        unset($i);

        # should never be empty, but just as a precaution ...
        if (!empty($part_ids)) {
            foreach ($components as $key => $component)
            {
                $components[$key]['part_id'] = $part_ids[$component['part_ref']];
            }

            # rm components from assoc part id
            foreach ($part_ids as $id)
            {
                $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($delete_components_sql, array($id)));
            }

            # insert components
            $admin_functions->insert_components($components);
        } else {
            echo 'Error!';
        }

        echo (!$error ? 'Success! File Successfully Imported.' : 'There be something wrong with the import. Please try again.');
    }
```

it's triggered through a button press and uses AJAX to handle it etc.

I'm not sure why a memory leak is occurring or why WordPress doesn't offer more useful error messages. I don't call that function.. so I'm guessing it's something WordPress is doing in the background when things are run.

My info:

> PHP 7.2.10
>   Apache 2.4
>   Linux Mint 19

Also happens on my server:

> PHP 7.1.25
>   Apache 2.4
>   CentOS 7.6.1810

WordPress running version: 4.9.8

Comment: Why are you using a custom php page and not defining your own AJAX hook or (even better) custom REST endpoint? If the csv is too large, can't you split this operation into multiple operations?

Comment: @kero what do you mean? :) All I've done is in my script.js file added an ajax function to a `.click` which points to this page ... never really done WP development - more of a Symfony/Magento dev - used to this way, so just assumed it would be ok haha

Comment: @kero qwll, csv is only 200 lines or so, WP should be able to handle that no?

Comment: You `require` some WP files. This is not the WordPress way, the documentation describes [how to do AJAX](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) or using the more modern [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). I haven't looked too deep in your code but the thing is: you break WP flow by including some files, so it is possible that default WP behaviour is broken. Instead, if you do it the WP way, you can be sure, that things like shutdown handlers work as intended

Comment: @kero ah my hatred for Wordpress only grows stronger! haha Any reason why it does it in a seemingly backwards way? (not trying to attack, it just doesn't make much logical sense)

Comment: Kero is right. How are you defining your URL to call this ajax script? It should not just call a file, you should use Wordpress `add_action` for your ajax function. So in js file make your call to WPs admin ajax URL and set data to your function name like `add_action('wp_ajax_my_function','my_function')` keep in mind there is also wp_ajax_nopriv if you're logged out.

Comment: When you route your ajax call this way through Wordpress, you include WP core and don't need to include those files manually. Like Kero said, you are likely causing WP core to fail doing it your way.

Comment: @treyBake [Create a custom REST endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#examples) - it is really easy. How is this a backwards way? You wouldn't go create a custom file and `require 'vendor/symfony/process/InputStream.php';`, but create a class, make use auf autoloading, etc. -> you would use symfony architecture. And here, you should use WP architecture

Comment: @kero no - I'd simply add the JS file to the module and call the controller and return the response - I've never run into any issues with use of AJAX this way until WP - but I'll read the link etc. and see what I can do :) ty for your help

Comment: @TimHallman I just call `url: PLUGIN_ROOT+ '/admin/inc/scripts/import-parts.php',`

Comment: @treyBake have a look here https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: A WP CLI command would have been a much better way of doing this, avoiding both the memory and the PHP time execution limits. Also, WP Admin AJAX is an ancient API, use a REST API endpoint as kero suggests. Also consider that your CSV may be too large to fit in the available memory, there won't be a config option you can change to just fix it unless you start cleaning up variables after you're finished with them, or you modify `php.ini` to give the script more memory

Comment: It's very likely that your `$admin_functions` variable is growing in size on each iteration loop and never cleaning up, until it fills memory. As I said though, this isn't a good fit for an AJAX call, and would be better done via a CLI command. Also, pinging an arbitrary theme/plugin PHP file in your site can be a security risk, as it will always work and has no authentication, even if the plugin is deactivated. Sadly we see no code for the `insert_parts` and `insert_components` methods so it's hard to advise

Comment: @TomJNowell why would a CLI command be a better fit out of interest? It takes in end-user input .. how would they access it via CLI?

Comment: @TomJNowell they're just insert statements for the data :)

Comment: @kero going through that doc page.. it's kinda unclear. Where do I add all of the code it gives? How does the JS call it? How do I post data from a form to the endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve, I agree with [Tom's comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321657/memory-leak-in-plugin-action?noredirect=1#comment475327_321657), that a WP-CLI command might be better. The advantage is that the command runs from php directly on the server (usually has no max execution time, loads different php.ini, etc.) and you don't need to involve the webserver.

---

If that is not possible, the next best way is probably to [create a custom REST endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/). WordPress has a class [`WP_REST_Controller`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_controller/), usually I write classes that `extend` this and work from there. For simplicity the following example is not using inheritence, but I try to keep to the same lingo.

**1. Register new route**

New/custom routes are registered via [`register_rest_route()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) like so

```
$version = 1;
$namespace = sprintf('acme/v%u', $version);
$base = '/import';

\register_rest_route(
    $namespace,
    $base,
    [
        [
            'methods' => \WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
                         // equals ['POST','PUT','PATCH']

            'callback' => [$this, 'import_csv'],
            'permission_callback' => [$this, 'get_import_permissions_check'],
            'args' => [],
            // used for OPTIONS calls, left out for simplicity's sake
        ],
    ]
);
```

This will create a new route that you can call via

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/acme/v1/import/
   default REST start-^       ^       ^
       namespace with version-|       |-base
```

**2. Define permissions check**

Maybe you need authentication? Use nonces?

```
public function get_import_permissions_check($request)
{
    //TODO: implement
    return true;
}
```

**3. Create your actual endpoint callback**

The method previously defined gets passed a [`WP_REST_Request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/) object, use that to access request body, etc. To stay consistent, it is usually best to return a [`WP_REST_Response`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_response/) instead of custom printing of JSON or similar.

```
public function import_csv($request)
{
    $data = [];
    // do stuff
    return new \WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
}
```

---

If you do all of this in OOP style, you'll get the following class

```
class Import_CSV
{

    /**
     * register routes for this controller
     */
    public function register_routes()
    {
        $version = 1;
        $namespace = sprintf('acme/v%u', $version);
        $base = '/import';

        \register_rest_route(
            $namespace,
            $base,
            [
                [
                    'methods' => \WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
                    'callback' => [$this, 'import_csv'],
                    'permission_callback' => [$this, 'get_import_permissions_check'],
                    'args' => [],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * endpoint for POST|PUT|PATCH /acme/v1/import
     */
    public function import_csv($request)
    {
        $data = [];
        // do stuff
        return new \WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
    }

    /**
     * check if user is permitted to access the import route
     */
    public function get_import_permissions_check($request)
    {
        //TODO: implement
        return true;
    }

}
```

But .. still 404? Yes, simply defining the class sadly doesn't work (no autoloading by default :( ), so we need to run `register_routes()` like so (in your plugin file)

```
require_once 'Import_CSV.php';
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    $import_csv = new \Import_CSV;
    $import_csv->register_routes();
});
```

Comment: this is clearer than the docs - ty :) one last question - how does my JS call it? :) E.g. I essentially have a form that allows user to import + select a product for that import (so it passes $_FILES and an $id) - where does the JS fit in for this?

Comment: If you hardcode namespace & base in the REST controller, just call that from JS. If not, you could use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to inject the REST url into a global namespace and use that. And then you work inside `import_csv()` as you do in your custom script right now

Comment: I fixed everything to point to a REST Endpoint and it still memory leaks :/

Comment: @treyBake And it's still pointing to the same file?

Comment: What do you mean pointing to the same file? o.O

Comment: @treyBake The original error message pointed to wp-includes/functions.php, didn't it?

Comment: Ah with ya, yeah still points there

Comment: @treyBake I probably don't have the time today to investigate this further. Have you ever worked with PHP debugging outside of frameworks? [debugging with xdebug](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=php%20debug%20memory%20leak%20xdebug) comes to mind

Comment: I've set my memory limit to `-1` and it returns a new error: `allocation size overflow -> c http://site.local/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:4:26778`

Comment: familiar with xdebug - though not installed due to laziness xD will configure and see if it returns anything more useful

Comment: @treyBake Did you solve this? (if so, how?) Or was my answer auto accepted by the system?

Comment: I solved it and marked your solution as accepted. I don't think my AJAX implementation was incorrect, or at least, the cause of the error. Now I understand it, I definitely prefer this methodology - hence my acceptance of your answer. However, I installed `xdebug` and debugged my function - turns out my `fputcsv` was erroring because $handle was a boolean and not opening the import file correctly. This was due to the `uploads/import` folder not existing on the server. Though, not sure why WordPress errors with a memory leak, to me it should return the actual error.. so WP still sucks ;)

Comment: but the error is resolved! So thank you :)

Comment: @treyBake Happy to hear you solved it! My +1 on your comment though goes for everything **except** the last sentence ;) WP can be fun

Comment: hahaha that's fair enough ;) I think WP can be fun, but done my way. I refuse to use HTML within the function declarations.. I will always opt to build html and echo the string haha xD but again thank you! wouldn't have done it without you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your functions file do something like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_import_parts_abc', 'import_parts_abc');
function import_parts_abc() {
    include_once('/admin/inc/scripts/import-parts.php');
    exit();

}
```

Then in your js file something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.my-button').click(function() {
jQuery.ajax({  
            type: 'GET',  
            url: ajaxurl,  
            data: { 
                action : 'import_parts_abc'
            },  
            success: function(textStatus){
                alert('processing complete')
            },
            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
                console.log(errorThrown);  
            }  
      }); 
});

});
```

Comment: This fixes the security issue, but doesn't address the problem the OP asked about. Also a REST API endpoint + `fetch()` would have been better

Comment: It should solve his error problem which is what the OP asked about? I would agree the REST API is slightly faster (15-25%), but that doesn't answer the OP's question regarding AJAX.

Comment: The users problem is they're running out of memory, AJAX was just us in the comments realising the OP was calling a PHP file directly and loading in WP

Comment: The memory leak was a result of improperly implementing AJAX.

Comment: @TimHallman not sure it is - it's a valid way of doing AJAX, in fact **all** of my other plugins use AJAX no worries this way, it's just for this particular function it doesn't play along

Comment: @treyBake it may work 99% of the time, but I don't believe it would be considered valid according to WP standards (which is why it fails 1% of the time). All the best though, hope you solve your issue.

Comment: @TimHallman I solved it! Using kero's answer and xdebug, I found the issue - $handle was false as `uploads/import` wasn't a valid folder path. Not sure why WordPress error the way it does with a memory leak instead of a fputcsv expects param 2 to be an object error... maybe some WP issues behind-the-scenes with handling errors like that :s